# ACRA sending a custom data REPORTFIELD

Tags: java, android, couchdb, acra, acralyzer

How to configure a CUSTOM_DATA field  with a couchdb ?

I want to set a config value to send with with the error. In the back end I have a couch db with an ACLARYZER web app.

This is the code on my Application.class in Android where I defined this custom data value.

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "https://user.cloudant.com/acra-report/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "user",
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "pass",
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
            ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA
    },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.reporte_error
)
public class my_applicaction  extends Application{

 @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
    ACRA.init(my_applicaction.this);
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue");
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(null);


}
}
```

Now the **question is** how to add the value in the couch db to get this custom data field. Or I have to define the custom data in the ACRALYZER?

thanks﻿

Comment: Hi @exequielc. What version of Acra you are using?

Comment: compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally it's more easy than I can imagine.

Simply put this line with every CUSTOM_DATA

```
 ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("NAME_VALUE1", "VALUE1");
```

Then your code is somthing like this.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    ACRA.init(Application.this);
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("NAME_VALUE1", "VALUE1");
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("NAME_VALUE2", "VALUE2");
    ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("NAME_VALUE3", "VALUE3");
}
```

The ACLARYZER  do the rest.